# Can't configure cmake to build standalone executable using cygwin

Tags: c++, cmake, cygwin, exe, clion

I need to build my c++ project that I created using CLion as standalone exe-file but I don't know how to do that!

Here is my CMakeList.txt:

[image: CMakeList.txt]

Here is my CLion Toolchain settings:

[image: TOOLCHAIN]

The settings is OK!

But when I build exe and run it i get error:

[image: CYGWIN1_ERROR]

It says that the program can't be run because "cygwin1.dll" is missing and reinstalling the program could help to fix it.

Anybody knows how to fix that? I can't find cygwin1.dll in cygwin installing client to fix it:

[image: install_client]

Comment: the `cygwin1.dll` is part of the `cygwin` package. Try to run your program from Cygwin terminal

Comment: @matzeri My goal is to build standalone exe file. How can I do that in my case?

Comment: do not use cygwin. Try mingw